# Brahmarishi Vishvamitra in Vedas and Itihasa

Tags: scripture, vedas, mahabharata, ramayana, vedanta

How is Brahmarishi Vishvamitra in the vedas different from what is mentioned about him in the itihasa?

Comment: What do you mean by different. There is no inconsistency between Vedas and itihasas

Comment: @Carmensandiego There is a lot of dissimilarity in the stories of Itihasas and Vedas. Take the story of Krishna, for example.

Comment: @vidyarthi - What was Krishna's story in vedas